# Accessing the Arcgis secured url using authentication ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, ios7, arcgis

Here I am trying to access the secured URL using the HTTP authentication. But still the data is coming null.
code:

```
{

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysecuredurl.com"];

    NSString *userName =@"abc@v.com";
    NSString *password =@"12345";

   NSError *myError = nil;

   NSMutableString *loginString = (NSMutableString*)[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, password];
  NSLog(@"loginstring=%@",loginString);

   NSString *authHeader = [@"Basic " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", loginString];
   NSLog(@"auth header =%@",authHeader);

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url
                                                          cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval: 3];
   NSLog(@"request %@",request);

[request addValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
   NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection
                    sendSynchronousRequest: request
                    returningResponse: &response
                    error: &myError];
       NSLog(@"data %@",data);

    NSLog(@"response %@",response);

    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSLog(@"result = %@",result);

}
```

Both data and response is null. Please do help me out in this. Is there any changes do I need to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your authentication string needs to be base64 encoded.  Try -

```
NSData *userPasswordData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64EncodedCredential = [userPasswordData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSString *authHeader= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", base64EncodedCredential]; NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url
                                                          cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval: 3];

[request addValue:authHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Comment: HeY! thanks for replying . but still the data is nil and 'm getting the error which is: NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSUnderlyingError=0xd35c8e0 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found.

Comment: The message is pretty clear - Check your host name and DNS settings.  I don't know what host you are trying to access so I can't test it

Comment: I need to pass the hostname also to authenticate the secured url? In that case can you please tell how can I pass the hostname to it?

Comment: No, you just need the host in `[NSURL URLWithString...]` but mysecuredurl.com isn't it.

Comment: No, I'm passing some secured url , not the one what i mentioned.

Comment: I assumed that, but the message is saying that that host is invalid.  Can you ping that host?  Browse to it from Safari? Have you double-checked the host address

Comment: i tried browsing the hostname in safari . but it says cant find the server.coz it is the secured one. and opens only in its own network.

Comment: If you can't open it in safari then you can't open it in your app.  The code I supplied just sends the username and password.  If you need a VPN connection or something then you need to set that up before running your app

Comment: But inside good dynamics it works. can you please tell me how I can host in [NSURL URLWithString...]. I meant the syntax.

Comment: If you are using Good then your app needs to run inside Good. It is a secured solution. An app running outside good cannot access data/hosts inside Good

Comment: so if I'm using Good, then do i need to host?

Comment: I am not an expert on Good, but I think you need to get your app published inside the Good container by the administrator

Comment: Hey! the url has json data. How can I create a json request for arcGIS?

Comment: There are lots of examples on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on how to parse JSON using iOS.  I suggest that you search and ask another question if you have a specific problem.